# Debian 8.6.0 (Jessie) systemd problems

Tags: debian

I am trying to get a command-line login prompt at boot up.

Somebody here suggested to type

systemctl set-default -f multi-user.target

However, this does not work for me. I am still getting a graphical login prompt. On the screen log I see:

Starting LSB: Gnome Display Manager

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The commandline prompt is provided by the `getty` service; it's probably already enabled.  If you're at the graphical login (GDM), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> should switch you to the first virtual console and give you a text login prompt.

---

If you don't want the graphical login to run, disable GDM.  (If you don't need it to run at all, consider uninstalling it entirely.)

- Assuming you just want to temporarily disable the graphical login (allows manually starting the service):

  ```
  $ sudo systemctl disable display-manager.service
  ```
- If you want to completely block the service from running (prevents manually starting the service):

  ```
  $ sudo systemctl mask display-manager.service
  ```

To re-enable the service later, use the `enable` or `unmask` parameter.

Comment: there is a bug in jessie where `getty` might fail to run when `systemd`, `plymouth`, and `gdm` are all installed.  it should be fixed but see https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=766462